# Recycler View not showing any data

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I am trying to implement recycler View in android but after adding it to the app it is not showing anything. I have searched online yet I am not able to figure out what am I doing wrong.
Also When I declare dashpercent and dashsubject (mentioned in adapter) in class RecyclerViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder the on writing :

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        dashboard_recycler_components data = dashlist.get(position);
        String sub = data.Subject;

        holder.dashpercent.setText(data.percentage);
        holder.dashsubject.setText(data.Subject);

    }
```

then dashpercent and dashsubject give an error that they are not declared.

Adapter

```
package com.example.attendance;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class RecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {


    private ArrayList<dashboard_recycler_components> dashlist;

    RecyclerAdapter(ArrayList<dashboard_recycler_components> a) {
        this.dashlist = a;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from((parent.getContext()));
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.attendace_card, parent, false);
        return new RecyclerViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        dashboard_recycler_components data = dashlist.get(position);
        String sub = data.Subject;
        TextView dashpercent = (TextView) holder.itemView.findViewById(R.id.dashPercent);
        TextView dashsubject = (TextView) holder.itemView.findViewById(R.id.dashSubject);
        ProgressBar dashProgress = (ProgressBar) holder.itemView.findViewById(R.id.recycler_progress);
        dashpercent.setText(data.percentage);
        dashsubject.setText(data.Subject);

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return dashlist.size();
    }

    public class RecyclerViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {


        RecyclerViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
        }

    }
}
```

dashboadfragment:

```
package com.example.attendance;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.ListAdapter;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class dashboardfragment extends Fragment {
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ArrayList<dashboard_recycler_components> subList = new ArrayList<>();
        dashboard_recycler_components a = new dashboard_recycler_components("DSA",33);
        dashboard_recycler_components b = new dashboard_recycler_components("DSA",33);
        dashboard_recycler_components c = new dashboard_recycler_components("DSA",33);
        dashboard_recycler_components d = new dashboard_recycler_components("DSA",33);
        dashboard_recycler_components e = new dashboard_recycler_components("DSA",33);
        dashboard_recycler_components f = new dashboard_recycler_components("DSA",33);
        dashboard_recycler_components g = new dashboard_recycler_components("DSA",33);
        dashboard_recycler_components h = new dashboard_recycler_components("DSA",33);
        dashboard_recycler_components i = new dashboard_recycler_components("DSA",33);
        dashboard_recycler_components j = new dashboard_recycler_components("DSA",33);
        subList.add(a);
        subList.add(b);
        subList.add(c);
        subList.add(d);
        subList.add(e);
        subList.add(f);
        subList.add(g);
        subList.add(h);
        subList.add(i);
        subList.add(j);
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_dashboard,container,false);
        RecyclerView  recycle = (RecyclerView)v.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view1);
        recycle.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
        recycle.setAdapter(new RecyclerAdapter(subList));

        return v;
    }
}
```

dashbord_recycler_componets:

```
package com.example.attendance;

public class dashboard_recycler_components {
    int percentage;
    String Subject;

    public dashboard_recycler_components(String a , int b){
        this.percentage = b;
        this.Subject = a;
    }

    public int getPercentage() {
        return percentage;
    }

    public String getSubject() {
        return Subject;
    }

    public void setPercentage(int percentage) {
        this.percentage = percentage;
    }

    public void setSubject(String subject) {
        this.Subject = subject;
    }
}
```

MainActivity:

```
package com.example.attendance;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;

import com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        BottomNavigationView bottomNav = findViewById(R.id.bottom_nav_bar);
        bottomNav.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(navListener);
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame_container,
                new homefragment()).commit();
    }

    private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener navListener = new
            BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {
                    Fragment frag = null;
                    switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
                        case R.id.dashboard:
                            frag = new dashboardfragment();
                            break;
                        case R.id.profile:
                            frag = new profilefragment();
                            break;
                        case R.id.home:
                            frag = new homefragment();
                            break;
                    }
                    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame_container,
                            frag).commit();
                    return true;
                }
            };





}
```

Comment: Do you have any error in the logcat? Also you should modify your property `Subject` to `subject`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `percentage` in `dashboard_recycler_components` is an `int` if you want to assign
your `percentage` is an `int` if you want to assign it to your `dashpercent` you have to first make this `int` a `String` such as : `dashpercent.setText(String.valueOf(data.percentage));`

PS:

You should rename your class object `dashboard_recycler_components` to `dashboardRecyclerComponents` and use `camelCase` instead of `snake_case`

Answer (score 0):

The Problem is you are trying to get the layout views inside onBindViewHolder and you can't this you can declare your viewes in your custom ViewHolder and get the views inside onBindViewHolder like this ... i think this gonna solve your problem

```
public class RecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAdapter.RecyclerViewHolder> {


private ArrayList<dashboard_recycler_components> dashlist;

RecyclerAdapter(ArrayList<dashboard_recycler_components> a) {
    this.dashlist = a;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public RecyclerViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from((parent.getContext()));
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.attendace_card, parent, false);
    return new RecyclerViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerViewHolder holder, int position) {
    dashboard_recycler_components data = dashlist.get(position);
    String sub = data.Subject;

    holder.dashpercent.setText(data.percentage);
    holder.dashsubject.setText(data.Subject);

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return dashlist.size();
}

public static class RecyclerViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    TextView dashpercent;
    TextView dashsubject;
    ProgressBar dashProgress;

    RecyclerViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        dashpercent = itemView.findViewById(R.id.dashPercent);
        dashsubject = itemView.findViewById(R.id.dashSubject);
        dashProgress = itemView.findViewById(R.id.recycler_progress);
    }

}
```

}